# A tool to organize menu bar apps in Mac OS X

Tags: osx, menu

I've been able to find http://www.macbartender.com/ that allows to organize and clean up Mac OS X menu bar.

Are there any alternatives to this application?

Comment: What don't you like about Bartender?

Comment: I am just surprised that I can't find any alternatives, there are usually more than one application for a given problem

Comment: Please list what features you want and then those that do use Macs (ie not me) can make better suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but some programs with similar features to Bartender are:

1. Zibity's '[Broomstick](http://www.zibity.com/broomstick)':

   > Broomstick is the easiest way to hide menubar icons that you don’t like. While most apps that create a menubar icon allow you to hide it, some apps don’t provide this option. Broomstick lets you take back control of your menubar!

   Screenshots:

   [image]
   [image]
2. [AccessMenuBarApps](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/38985/accessmenubarappsa):

   > AccessMenuBarApps is a simple app that gives the user instant access to all menubar apps by showing a reduced app menu (so that there is more space for menubar apps). Activating/Deactivating of the reduced app menu can be triggered by keyboard shortcut, mouse gesture, click on the menubar icon or click on the dock icon.

   Screeenshot:

   [image]